# How to display content using JavaScript on Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, web

I'm writing a page which will show the min and max time the server ran through, those information are stored within a list, I wrote some JavaScript, but don't how to display

sample like:

```
min time: XX:XX
max time: xx:xx
```

they cannot be added as `onClick()` or `MouseOver()`, they are just regular content.

So what should I do, can anybody give me some good ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No offence but Why did you pin jQuery tag to this post ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a web part on a page would do the trick.

**Add a web part**

Edit your page
 and add a web part - Content editor (CEWP)

**Edit the CEWP**

Paste script into CEWP through Editing Tools>Format Text
Html> Edit HTML Source

**Better still!**

If you have the code in a .js file
edit CEWP and add file location on sharepoint